# testing ASP.NET membership provider Duplicate Email on create user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, tdd, membership-provider

I' trying to exercise membership and role provider methods. So far so good, but I'm stuck currently on Create user with submited duplicated email.

```
    [Test]
    public void can_create_user_with_given_duplic_Email()
    {
        MembershipCreateStatus status = new MembershipCreateStatus();
        provider.CreateUser("FirstUser", _Password, _Email, null, null, true, Guid.NewGuid(), out status);
        provider.CreateUser("SecondUser", _Password, _Email, null, null, true, Guid.NewGuid(), out status);

        Assert.AreEqual(MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateEmail, status);
    }
```

as you can see I'm expecting Duplicate Email message from MembershipCreateStatus.

Error message I'm actually got with running this test is following

```
can_create_user_with_given_duplic_Email has failed:
  Expected: DuplicateEmail
  But was:  ProviderError
```

Just to mention that provider.CreateUser() works with no problem.

Comment: Are both users actually created successfully in your ASPNET_Membership table?

Comment: Why are you testing Membership Provider? Is this your custom implementation of Provider or you're using ASP.NET Membership Provider?

Comment: custom implementation, and by the way I'm handled correctly. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `requiresUniqueEmail="false"` to allow duplicate emails.

```
<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" 
         type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, 
                  System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, 
                  Culture=neutral, 
                  PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" 
         connectionStringName="SqlConnection" 
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
         enablePasswordReset="true" 
         requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
         requiresUniqueEmail="false"
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" 
         minRequiredPasswordLength="6" 
         minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
         passwordAttemptWindow="10" 
         applicationName="MyApp"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
```

Comment: This is an old question and answer, but ASP.NET membership is still used in apps today, even if it has fallen out of favor for new projects. I didn't know this was set in the web.config file, so thanks for providing that answer! I inherited a web app from someone else at my workplace, hence the confusion.